# SparkSQL Split String

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a file with several lines. For example

```
A               B       C    
awer.ttp.net    Code    554
abcd.ttp.net    Code    747
asdf.ttp.net    Part    554
xyz.ttp.net     Part    747
```

I want to make a SparkSQL statement to split just column a of the table and I want a new row added to the table D, with values awe, abcd, asdf, and xyz.

I am looking for SQL not Scala or some other language

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple example Using SQL with Spark

```
import spark.implicits._
val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("awer.ttp.net","Code", 554),
  ("abcd.ttp.net","Code", 747),
  ("asdf.ttp.net","Part", 554),
  ("xyz.ttp.net","Part", 747)
)).toDF("A","B","C")

data.createOrReplaceTempView("tempTable")
data.sqlContext.sql("SELECT A, B, C, SUBSTRING_INDEX(A, '.', 1) as D  from tempTable").show
```

Output:

```
+------------+----+---+----+
|           A|   B|  C|   D|
+------------+----+---+----+
|awer.ttp.net|Code|554|awer|
|abcd.ttp.net|Code|747|abcd|
|asdf.ttp.net|Part|554|asdf|
| xyz.ttp.net|Part|747| xyz|
+------------+----+---+----+
```

I hope this helps!